# Visual Studio 2019 and ReSharper: deactivate Studio code analysis

Tags: visual-studio-2019, resharper, microsoft.codeanalysis

I had Studio 2019 Community Edition installed, as well ReSharper. Since we use ReSharper for code analysis, we deactivated Studio code analysis by .editorconfig with only 2 lines:

```
root = true
dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.severity = none
```

Everything worked fine (and still does on another PC).

Now I got a new PC, installed Win 10 from scratch, as well Studio and ReSharper. Now Visual Studio always does code analysis and comments/suggests several issues. Even if I reconfigure issues severity to None, I do not get any changes to my .editorconfig, but still analysing the code.

How can I get rid of Studio code analysis?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but take a look at [this article](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2020/05/11/story-csproj-large-solutions-memory-usage/). It describes a way to disable Roslyn-based Visual Studio features through the project properties used by Visual Studio design-time builds. This approach significantly improves memory usage on large solutions.

Comment: I tried the provided Directory.Build.targets, but got the following problems: WinForms designer not working anymore (as mentioned there; guess the type of our projects :-( ), cannot see members of partial classes (like InitializeComponent in .designer.cs) in source editor combo box. Perhaps I have to dig a little deeper in that article and linked references.